# Как dataLayer заполнить готовым массивом?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    title: 'title',
    value: 'value'
  },
  {
    title: 'title',
    value: 'value'
  },
  {
    title: 'title',
    value: 'value'
  },
  {
    title: 'title',
    value: 'value'
  }
]
```

мне нужно массив выше, передавать в dataLayer(примерный вариант ниже)

```js
window.dataLayer.push(
  {'event': [arr]}
)
```

не имею представления как вообще работать с dataLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел ответ:

Нужно запускать функцию записи в процеccе заполнения самого массива

```js
window.dataLayer.push(
  {'event': JSON.stringify(arr)}
)
```